# How to work around "non-static class T cannot be referenced from a static context"?

Tags: java

How to write a Java function which simply takes an argument of any type, prints it and returns it?

In Scheme I am used to write the following macro:

```lisp
(define-syntax dump
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ arg) (let ((value arg))
               (display 'arg)
               (display " -> ")
               (display value)
               (newline)
               arg))))
```

Calling it `(+ 1 (dump (* 2 3)))` would return 7 and print `(* 2 3) -> 6`.

I tried something similar in Java:

```
public class Debug<T>
{
    public static T dump (T arg)
    {
        System.err.println (arg);
        return arg;
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
non-static class T cannot be referenced from a static context
```

How to solve this?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If I would be allowed I would use [Kawa](http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You implemented your class as an inner class inside some other. In that case you must mark the class as `static`.

But, the real answer is: you don't need the class at all, you just need the method:

```
public static <T> T dump(T arg) { ... }
```

As a side note, I use the same trick in my code, but I always include a msg argument for easier dump reading/grepping:

```
public static <T> T dump(String msg, T arg) { ... }
```

Comment: Ok this compiles but does not print the string. Instead it prints `[Ljava.lang.String;@b28f30`.

Comment: print arg.oString(). But again that depends on implementation of toString() of the object

Comment: @ceving Arrays are a special case in Java. They don't have a meaningful `toString` implementation. If you need to handle them, use `System.out.println(msg + (arg instanceof Object[]? Arrays.toString((Object[])arg) : arg));`

Comment: If you need to support *primitive* arrays, then you are in real trouble. It will take a pile of boilerplate to make it print reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I got it:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Debug
{
    public static <T> T dump (T arg)
    {
        System.err.println(arg instanceof Object[] ? 
                           Arrays.toString((Object[])arg) : arg);
        return arg;
    }
}
```

Lovely Scheme I grieve for you...